# rascal cannot add breakpoint while debugging

Tags: rascal

Somehow, debugging rascal in eclipse doesnt work for me.
I'm running rascal in eclipse Luna.
Everyting works, debug Start.rsc as application starts the rascal console in debug.
But clicking in the marging does not add a breakpoint no matter what.
Do I have to use a specific editor? (now using the java editor)

cheers, Ibanezje

Comment: Could you try in eclipse mars? Moreover, there are some language constructs that you cannot (at the moment) put a breakpoint on.

Comment: Awesome, Eclipse Mars did the trick. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: upgrade to Eclipse Mars.
Then with the 'impulse editor' you will be able to debug.